# ManyToOne as array (ManyToMany equivalent)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

**[SETTINGS]**

- Symfony 3.4
- `Forme` entity
- `Limon` entity (part from a house stairs)

**[PRBLEM]**

I have a `Limon` which can have different shapes (`Forme`).

The thing is, instead of `ManyToMany` relation to define the allowed shapes (`Forme`), I would like to use `ManyToOne`, and store multiple `id` as simple array, thus allowing me to select the allowed shapes (`Forme`) when I create a `Limon`

Can someone tell me how I should modify my code to fit my needs please?

<kbd>**AppBundle/Entity/Limon.php**</kbd>

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Forme", inversedBy="limon")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $forme;

/**
 * Set forme
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Forme $forme
 *
 * @return Limon
 */
public function setForme(\AppBundle\Entity\Forme $forme)
{
    $this->forme = $forme;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get forme
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Forme
 */
public function getForme()
{
    return $this->forme;
}
```

<kbd>**AppBundle/Entity/Forme.php**</kbd>

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Limon", mappedBy="forme")
 */
private $limon;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct() {
    $this->limon=new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add limon
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Limon $limon
 *
 * @return Forme
 */
public function addLimon(\AppBundle\Entity\Limon $limon) {
    $this->limon[]=$limon;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove limon
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Limon $limon
 */
public function removeLimon(\AppBundle\Entity\Limon $limon) {
    $this->limon->removeElement($limon);
}

/**
 * Get limon
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getLimon() {
    return $this->limon;
}
```

<kbd>**AppBundle/Form/LimonType.php**</kbd>

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('forme', EntityType::class, array(
                'class'=>'AppBundle:Forme',
                'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('f')
                              ->where('f.actif=1');
                },
            ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 3, when you want to do a Many-to-Many, the simpliest thing to do is to create a table between the two tables (here Lime and Forme).

Example :

You create a table : hasShape ou (aLaForme)

In Lime entity you will have an array of references: $hasShapes : **One to Many**

In Shape entity you will have an array of references: $hasShapes : **One to Many**

In hasShape you will have the reference of **one object of Lime** $lime and **one object of shape** $shape : **Many to One**

When you will create a Lime, you will show a table of shapes.

To save you have to create an object Lime -> get the ID of this lime -> get the ID of the shape selected -> save the two IDs in hasShape.

Comment: Yep... That is precisely what I want to avoid. The shape(`Forme`) is set in stone, it will never be edited. Thus I find it pointless to have a 3rd table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [One-To-Many, Unidirectional with Join Table](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table). Referring to your code it should look like this:

`AppBundle/Entity/Limon.php`

```
/**
 * Many User have Many Phonenumbers.
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Forme")
 * @JoinTable(name="lime_form",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="limon_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="form_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
 *      )
 */
private $forme;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct() {
    $this->limon= new ArrayCollection();
}
```

And that's all. The above code will generate a linking table between limon and form table